# Plugin class is deprecated in Phonegap

Tags: android, cordova

i had observed the Plugin class in Phonegap is deprecated , So what is the replacement of plugin now, how can i communicate between java and JavaScript with out using JavaScript Interface class and plugin class

thanking 
you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The plugins have changed a bit in the recent release, instead of extending the PluginClass it now extends CordovaPlugin. You can find how to create plugins in the official docs.

[Link to the android plugin development guide](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.4.0/guide_plugin-development_android_index.md.html#Developing%20a%20Plugin%20on%20Android)

```
public class Echo extends CordovaPlugin {
    @Override
    public boolean execute(String action, JSONArray args, CallbackContext callbackContext) throws JSONException {
        if (action.equals("echo")) {
            String message = args.getString(0); 
            this.echo(message, callbackContext);
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    private void echo(String message, CallbackContext callbackContext) {
        if (message != null && message.length() > 0) { 
            callbackContext.success(message);
        } else {
            callbackContext.error("Expected one non-empty string argument.");
        }
    }
}
```